# I would like to automate the reading of PDF documents into R using pdf_text

Tags: r, pdf, download

I currently have a code to extract certain details within a PDF document. However, as i have thousands of other PDF documents to extract information from, I would like to automate this process. I am using the pdf_text option to read PDFs into R. My code looks something like this:

```
library(pdftools)

x <- pdf_text("Test.pdf")   
y1 <- str_split(x, "\r")

#pdf output contains a total of 7 lists

a <- y1 [[4]]
b <- c(a[4],a[11:13]) #Obtain only rows 4, 11 to 13 from list 4

n2 <- y1[[3]]
n3 <- c(n2[3]) #Obtain only rows 3 from list 3

n <- y1[[5]]
n1 <- c(n[3]) #Obtain only rows 3 from list 5

c <- y1[[6]]
d <- c(c[4:18]) #Obtain only rows 4 to 18 from list 6

e <- c(n3,b,d,n1) #Combining all necessary information into one list

z <- substr(s[1:21], start = 15, stop = 200) #to remove white spaces between quotes

Name <- z[1]
InterestedParty <- z[2]
TotalOwnBefore <- substr(z[11], start = 97, stop = 120)
Ownership <- list(NM = Name, Party = InterestedParty, OwnBefore = TotalOwnBefore)

write.csv(Ownership, file="MyData.csv")
```

The above code allows me to output a file for a single company. However, I have thousands other PDFs ("Test_1.pdf" to "Test_1000.pdf") to be read. Is there a way to automate the reading of the PDF files into R with pdf_text? Would also be great if there's a way for me to store all results into a single file instead of one firm per file.

Answer (score 0):

I have since managed to automate the process using a for loop as follows:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
    x <- paste("Test_",i,".pdf", sep="")
    y <- pdf_text(print(x))
    total <- strsplit(y, "\r")
    print(y1)
}
```